# Capture Dialog Box Edit Text Changes in Fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, dialog

I’m in Android Studio version Chipmunk with one patch. I’m writing in Kotlin, a language I find is just beautiful. I have a dialog box over a fragment where I want to capture the changes in the edit text box as they happen. I’ve tried with straightforward code found here in Stack Overflow but I think the fragment can’t view the dialog box.

Following is code used:

```
private fun dlgFind() {
    try {
        //val sTxt: EditText = findViewById(R.id.txtStock)
        val sTxt = binding.txtMeds
        val spannable: Spannable = SpannableString(sTxt.text.toString())
        sTxt.setText(spannable.toString()) // clears highlighted text
        val dialog = Dialog(requireContext(), R.style.RoundedCornersDialogFind)
        dialog.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND) // makes frag text readable
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dlg_find)
        // tried to max dialog window to full width of screen
        //dialog.window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        val btnFind = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnGo) as ImageButton
        val txtFind = dialog.findViewById(R.id.editFind) as EditText
        txtFind.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
        txtFind.isFocusable = true
        //txtFind.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
        txtFind.requestFocus()
        txtFind.postDelayed({
            txtFind.requestFocus()
            val imm = context?.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
            imm?.showSoftInput(txtFind, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        }, 1)
        btnFind.setOnClickListener { dialog.dismiss()
            gsFindBoxTxt = txtFind.text.toString()
            sTxt.requestFocus()
            //sTxt.setText(spannable.toString()) // clears highlighted text
            findWithDlg() // method finds strings
        }
        //dialog.setOnCancelListener { editHours() }
        dialog.window?.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
        dialog.show()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        val methodName = object {}.javaClass.enclosingMethod?.name
        Toast.makeText(context, methodName.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Attempt to read from dialog box in fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    try {
        val sEditTxt = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editFind)
        sEditTxt?.doOnTextChanged { _, _, _, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(context, "!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
        if (sEditTxt?.text != null) {
            sEditTxt.doAfterTextChanged {
                Toast.makeText(context, "!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                findWithDlg()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Note I have tried boilerplate TextWatcher code too and I can't return view in onCreate because I'm using binding throughout the fragment. The return in onCreate is to the binding.root. And even in onDestroyView the last line is _binding = null. Maybe remove all binding and revert to using views?

I've also tried these in the dialog method (function) to no avail yet...

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I figured out how to listen to the text changes. I set following in the dialog method:

```
        dialog.setOnShowListener { txtFind.doOnTextChanged { _, _, _, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(context, "Text Change", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } 
        }
```